# Discard row in fnCreatedRow using Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've got a datatable I'm working with, and I'm essentially trying to discard the row about to be created if certain conditions are met (specifically, if the object it's associated with has been removed)

I've been working in the fnCreatedRow function, with my latest attempt looking something like this:

```
"fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    var row = $(nRow);
    var obj_id = aData.id;
    var obj = objects[obj_id];
    if (!obj) //Associated object is gone, so I want to discard the row
    {
        theDataTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
    }
    else
    {/*Various things with rows I don't want to discard*/}
}
```

This hasn't worked, the row still shows up as usual. Is there some way to discard the row when it would be created? Or some effective way to ensure it gets deleted right after it's been created?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I seem to have resolved my problem by putting the `theDataTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);` inside a `setTimeout` (with a delay of 1ms). This seems a little hackier than I'd like, particularly since I've been dealing with problems resulting from race conditions in JS more than I'd like to lately. I'm still very much open to better solutions.